# Incentives to IT Engineers completing certifications successfully

Tags: salary, recruitment, bonus

I have a team of 6 IT engineers and would like to establish a good incentive model for them.
At the current state we are paying an amount to each certification acquired.
Is there any other way the company can incentivy someone who passed their exams?

Comment: Why don't you just ask your team what *they* want?

Comment: "paying an amount to each certification acquired" what does that mean? what eaxtly do you pay? If a certificate takes a three weeks course and one day exam and costs 5000, what exactly do you pay for?

Comment: Also, identify why the company needs IT engineers to be certified. How do those certifications help anyone? Are there any alternatives that are better (such as serving on a standardization committee)?

Answer (score 2):

1. Allow time for training
2. Pay for courses (e.g pluralsight or udemy)
3. Pay for exams
4. Pay rise (or bonus) for completing the exam.

Nothing else needed. If a company won't do at least three of the above, I'll be incentivized to take the exam, then move on. Cash is king.

Sounds like you're pretty much there.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get the employees to get the certification: carrot or stick.

One way to get everybody certified is to either require it before hiring an employee or giving them x months to complete the certification process. If they can't pass the exam, then they are either let go or they are moved to another position.

The carrot is to give them the time to study, have the company pay for a training class, and then pay for the test. Some will do this upfront, others will reimburse after the test is passed.

Both ways can be used the company pays for everything, but also gives a deadline.

The tougher thing is what to do about current employees that don't have the certification. Unless you are willing to lose good employees by giving them a deadline, and then documenting the requirement, and then letting them go if they ignore the requirement; the carrot approach has to be strong enough to get them to want the certification. That would involve a bonus, or pay increase or an opportunity for advancement.